# Bind asyncData() with client side data the second time in SSR Nuxtjs vue

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Initial load of the page, data gets loaded with `asyncData`(). But I select another `location` , the data changes onchange of `location` and binds to `dlist`,   But when i refresh my page it again  selects my default `location` as Bangalore and i get my old `dlist` .

My question is suppose i save my `location` value in a cookie,how do i access inside `asyncData` method. Or on initial load ow do i call only `asyncData` and rest of the times when pageloaded for 2nd or 3rd time(suppose i go to next page and click on back) only `created` method. can anyone help me

```
 async asyncData () {

        let dList = []
     let location="Bangalore";
    //Location keep on changing, default can be Bangalore. It is got from the location user selects

    await fireDb.collection("drive_car")
                  .where("location", "==",location ).get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          cdList.push({
                      key: doc.id,
                      carbrand: doc.data().carbrand,
                      carclass: doc.data().carclass                 
                    });
        });
      });
    return {
      dList: dList

    }
      },
```

Comment: nuxt.js != next.js